# How do I make this button to call the function only once?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have a button on my HTML page that calls a function to print numbers from JavaScript. I want the button to only execute the function once. Right now it can execute as many times as you click the button and that ruins the output on the page. I tried to empty the array after the function prints numbers but it didn't work as the function would just print 50 then.

Here is my code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="decimal_table()">Generate Table</button>
<button id = "clear_pos" type="button" onclick="reset_button()">Clear</button>
<script>

  const real_array = [];
  const binary_array = [];
  const octal_array = [];
  const hex_array = [];

  function decimal_table ()
  {


     for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
       {
        real_array.push(i);
        binary_array.push(i.toString(2).padStart(8, 0));
        octal_array.push(i.toString(8));
        hex_array.push(i.toString(16));

        document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = real_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("binaries").innerHTML = binary_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("octals").innerHTML = octal_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = hex_array.join(" ");
       }
  }

   function reset_button ()
   {
     for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
       {
        real_array.shift(i);
        binary_array.shift(i);
        octal_array.shift(i);
        hex_array.shift(i);

        document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = real_array;
        document.getElementById("binaries").innerHTML = binary_array;
        document.getElementById("octals").innerHTML = octal_array;
        document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = hex_array;
       }
   } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a variable called something like isClicked outside the function scope and check the variable in the function before doing anything

```
<button type="button" onclick="decimal_table()">Generate Table</button>
<script>
  var isClicked = false;
  const real_array = [];
  const binary_array = [];
  const octal_array = [];
  const hex_array = [];

  function decimal_table ()
  {

      if(!isClicked){
     for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
       {
        real_array.push(i);
        binary_array.push(i.toString(2).padStart(8, 0));
        octal_array.push(i.toString(8));
        hex_array.push(i.toString(16));

        document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = real_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("binaries").innerHTML = binary_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("octals").innerHTML = octal_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = hex_array.join(" ");
        isClicked = true;
       }
      }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: This works but I need the function to specifically not print twice when the button is clicked. If I call the reset function, which erases the value in arrays. I want the generate button to work again. Just not print twice if the user accidently clicks on it again. Please check the edit in code.

Comment: just set the variable isClicked to false in the reset function

Comment: Yes now it works as I wanted to. Thank You for the help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to call click function in `HTML` template instead you can achieve the result in pure javascript.

Just use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListner` to the button click.

```js
  const real_array = [];
  const binary_array = [];
  const octal_array = [];
  const hex_array = [];

  const genTable = document.getElementById('generate-table');
  const resetBtn = document.getElementById('clear_pos');
  genTable.addEventListener('click',decimal_table)
  resetBtn.addEventListener('click',reset_button)

  function decimal_table ()
  {

     for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
       {
        real_array.push(i);
        binary_array.push(i.toString(2).padStart(8, 0));
        octal_array.push(i.toString(8));
        hex_array.push(i.toString(16));

        document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = real_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("binaries").innerHTML = binary_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("octals").innerHTML = octal_array.join(" ");
        document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = hex_array.join(" ");
       }
      genTable.removeEventListener('click',decimal_table);
  }

function reset_button ()
   {
     for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
       {
        real_array.shift(i);
        binary_array.shift(i);
        octal_array.shift(i);
        hex_array.shift(i);

        document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = real_array;
        document.getElementById("binaries").innerHTML = binary_array;
        document.getElementById("octals").innerHTML = octal_array;
        document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = hex_array;
       }
       genTable.addEventListener('click',decimal_table)
   }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="generate-table">Generate Table</button>
<button id = "clear_pos" type="button" >Clear</button>
<span id="numbers"></span>
<br><br>
<span id="binaries"></span>
<br><br>
<span id="octals"></span>
<br><br>
<span id="hex"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the event listerner, no need for additional variables.

```html
<button type="button" onclick="decimal_table(this)">Generate Table</button>

<script>
  function decimal_table(el) {
    // remove the event
    el.removeAttribute("onclick")
    console.log('clicked')
    
    // ..rest of your code
  }
</script>
```